# QWidget "access violation" exeption

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation, qwidget

A have a class, inherited from QWidget and Ui_Form (automaticaly generated class, appears when you create a .ui in Qt). It looks like

```
class MyClass: public QWidget, public Ui_Form {}
```

Ui_Form has some members, which connected with relevant widgets in the .ui file (for example, QLineEdits, QButtons, etc).

```
class Ui_Form {
public:
QLineEdit *fileNameEdit;

    void setupUi(QWidget *Form) {
    fileNameEdit = new QLineEdit(layoutWidget);
    fileNameEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("fileNameEdit"));
    }
}
```

As MyClass is inherited from Ui_Form, I can use this membes. But, when I try to do something, I have an exeption "Access violation reading location". For example:

```
fileNameEdit->setText("String");
```

Can somebody give an advice?

Comment: And you do it after setupUi has run?

Comment: A [glance at the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) shows that you need to call `setupUi(this) in your constructor. Do you?

Comment: Yes, I ran setupUI. And members not equal NULL, of couse. But, the mistake appears anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are incorporating the `Ui_Form` part is not how [Qt proposes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) it by default. If you look into this [button example](https://forum.qt.io/topic/81616/destructor-called-twoice) you can see how the ui part is incorporated diferently:

**Header file**

```
#ifndef BUTTON_H
#define BUTTON_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Button;
}

class Button : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Button(int n, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Button();

private slots:
    void removeRequested();

signals:
    void remove(Button* button);
private:
    Ui::Button *ui;
};

#endif // BUTTON_H
```

**CPP code**

```
#include "button.h"
#include "ui_button.h"

Button::Button(int n, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Button)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setText("Remove button "+QString::number(n));
    addAction(ui->actionRemove);
    connect(ui->actionRemove,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(removeRequested()));
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(removeRequested()));
}

Button::~Button()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Button::removeRequested()
{
    emit remove(this);
}
```

The main difference is that I believe you are not calling `Ui_From::setupUi` function. It is clear to me that you do not need to follow the Qt suggested template (incorporating the ui as a class member rather than inheriting from it), however, it is much clearer from my point of view if you follow the Qt suggestions.

Comment: Indeed, including the `Ui_Form` through multiple inheritance is not the best solution: it increases the dependencies of the users of `MyClass` and exposes the members of the UI (they are all public, although you can avoid this through protected inheritance instead).